# How to solve the "program not responding" problem when calling matlab function from python?

Tags: python, matlab

It's my first time to call matlab function from python. I defined a matlab function in a '''.mat''' file, then used the matlab.engine to call the function by passing a 8000000*1 mlarray parameter. Then the application turned to unresponsive and it taked about 30s to recover. So i guess it was because the function call may passing value copy instead of reference or pointer that took a long time. I'm wondering am i right, and if i'm right, how can i solve the problem?

Comment: You defined `matlab` function in a `.mat` file? Why? Generally, `matlab` function extensions are `.m`

Comment: Sorry Typo, my bad. It is in .m file. Do u have any idea?